# Additive Color Mixing (Blending) of images in Universal Windows XAML

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have a image of a scene with default lighting. Let's call this `image_baseline`.

I have another image of the same scene, but an extra red spot light is added. Let's call this `image_with_extra_red`.  Some surfaces show a lot of red, while other surfaces remain unchanged since the red spot light does not uniformly light the scene.  No place in this picture is darker than the original since the default lighting was not removed, just a red spot is added.

I have another image of the same screen, but extra green light is added just like the above. Let's call this `image_extra_green`.

Likewise, I have `image_extra_blue`.

Now I have 3 variables.  `Percent_of_extra_red, percent_of_extra_green, percent_of_extra_blue`.

I would like to add to image_baseline the proportions of the extra color lighting.

Pseudo code :

```
red_adder = image_with_extra_red - image_baseline; // now red_adder contains only the incremental effect of the red light

green_adder = image_with_extra_green - image_baseline;

blue_adder = image_with_extra_blue - image_baseline;

new_picture = image_baseline + (Percent_of_extra_red * red_adder ) + (Percent_of_extra_green * green_adder ) + (Percent_of_extra_blue * blue_adder )
```

The purpose of the above is to allow the user to control the intensity of the added red, green or blue spot light.

Hoping this can be done by overlaying 4 pictures in `XAML` and binding 3 variables `Percent_of_extra_red` , `Percent_of_extra_green`, and `blue`.

If it makes it easier, `red_adder`, `green_adder`, and `blue_adder` can be constructed offline with some graphic sw.

Comment: Since you've based the 3 'extra' images off of RGB, you could bind their opacity with a converter that will change 0.0-1.0 that the opacity property expects into 0-255; then have 3 sliders with values ranging 0-255 or something control the R, G and B for the user to tweak as they wish. That should allow colour mixing.

Comment: I don't follow.  Say the red image is on top, then I set it's opacity to not being opaque, all other images behind will be hidden.  What I need is that red gets added by the red image, but other colors are not affected.